# problema al asignar un valor a mi input con jquery - k.fn.init(1)

Tags: jquery

estoy intentando asignarle un el valor de mis rows de mi datatable a un input, pero tengo la siguiente situacion, al darle un console.log a la variable que me entrega el valor deseado, este me muestra correctamente este valor, pero al momento de asignar ese valor a mi input, me recibe esto `k.fn.init(1)`

dejo a continuación el console.log del valor deseado (n_clase) y lo que recibe mi input (clase)

**Codigo**

```
var dt = $("#horarioPracticoEditar_dt").DataTable();
var n_clase = parseFloat(dt.rows().count()) + 1;
var clase = $('#numero_clase').val(n_clase);

console.log(
  [
    n_clase,
    clase
  ]);
```

**console.log**

```
(2) [3, k.fn.init(1)]
 0: 3
 1: k.fn.init [input#numero_clase]
 length: 2
 __proto__: Array(0)
```

por cierto, también intente de esta forma y obtuve el mismo resultado

```
var clase = $('#numero_clase').val(parseFloat(dt.rows().count()) + 1);
```

Comment: Cuando asignas un valor al value `var clase = $('#numero_clase').val(n_clase);` no está hecho para devolver nada. Asignas el valor a la propiedad `value`. Para conseguir el valor de `value` tienes que ponerlo sin ningun parametro. Así que despues de la línea de `...val(...)` pon `var clase=$('#numero_clase').val();` para que realmente te devuelva la propiedad, esto pasa porque te devuelve el objeto entero modificado ya que lo has actualizado. [Api Jquery -> val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: @Jose muchas gracias, tenia una idea errónea de como hacer los console.log entonces, muchas gracias, me sirvió a la perfección!

Comment: Lo añado a una respuesta, ya que te ha servido

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problema:

El principal problema es la idea errónea de que devuelve `$('#numero_clase').val(n_clase);`.
`$('#numero_clase').val(n_clase);` devuelve el objeto modificado para su posterior uso
Y `objeto.val()` devuelve correctamente el `value` actual

### Solución:

En vez de utilizar la salida de `$('#numero_clase').val(n_clase);` utilizar `$('#numero_clase').val();` sin parametros para que devuelva correctamente la propiedad `value`.

De está forma esa parte de código quedaría así:

```
$('#numero_clase').val(n_clase);
var clase = $('#numero_clase').val();
```

[Api jquery -> val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/)